# How to create azure machine learning resource using terraform resource providers?

Tags: azure, terraform, azure-machine-learning-service, azure-rm

I wants to create azure machine learning workspace using terraform scripts.Is there any terraform provider to achieve this.

Comment: Any more questions? Does it solve your problem? If yes, please accept it. If no, give the response.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the meantime Microsoft has added a Terraform resource for ML Workspace in the Azure Provider. This should make any custom scripting obsolete.

https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/azurerm/r/machine_learning_workspace.html

```
resource "azurerm_machine_learning_workspace" "example" {
  name                    = "example-workspace"
  location                = azurerm_resource_group.example.location
  resource_group_name     = azurerm_resource_group.example.name
  application_insights_id = azurerm_application_insights.example.id
  key_vault_id            = azurerm_key_vault.example.id
  storage_account_id      = azurerm_storage_account.example.id

  identity {
    type = "SystemAssigned"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

While Charles gave some valid work around of this, I am working on creating those ML related resources for terraform-provider-azurerm. Please check this PR out: https://github.com/terraform-providers/terraform-provider-azurerm/pull/5696

Once this PR gets approved, merged and released, you will be able to create ML workspaces natively using terraform.
Other ml related resources are also on schedule.

Answer (score 3):

As I know, Terraform does not provide the API in Azure providers to create Azure Machine Learning.

So in my experience, you can only achieve your purpose with the help of the [Azure Template](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/templates/microsoft.machinelearning/allversions) and Azure Tool such as [Azure CLI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/ext/azure-cli-ml/ml?view=azure-cli-latest) in Terraform script.

If you use the Azure Template, then you can use the model `azurerm_template_deployment` to execute your template to create ML.

If you want to use the Azure CLI, then you can use the model `null_resource` to execute your CLI command locally. You can follow the steps [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/machine-learning/how-to-manage-workspace-cli). And also here is the example for Terraform:

```
resource "null_resource" "cluster" {

  provisioner "local-exec" {
    # here is your CLI command to create the ML
    command = ""
  }
}
```

Comment: How to capture the output in null_resource?

Comment: @Mithun Well, I didn't know you need to capture the result before. But if you want, you need to use the [`data source`](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/external/data_source.html) instead of the `null_resource`.

Answer (score 0):

check this - https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/azurerm/r/cognitive_account.html

but i think there is no direct module there you can check in official terraform docs - https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/azurerm/

Comment: If there is no direct module, what is the possible way to achieve this?

Comment: You can create using SDK-Python check this - 
1) https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/python/api/overview/azureml-sdk/?view=azure-ml-py

2) https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/python/api/azureml-core/azureml.core.workspace.workspace?view=azure-ml-py